# PHP get single value from MySQL with variable

Tags: php, function, select, mysqli, prepared-statement

I can't seem to get simple query working to find UserID from the table of Users by UserEmail

I have simple function to suppose to return UserID
**functions.php**

```
function get_userID($UEml) 
{
// Check database connection
  if( ($DB instanceof MySQLi) == false) {
    return array(status => false, message => 'MySQL connection is invalid');
  }
  $qSQL = "SELECT UsID FROM Users WHERE UsEml=? LIMIT 1";
  $qSQL = $DB->prepare($qSQL);
  $UEml = $DB->real_escape_string($UEml);
  $qSQL->bind_param("s", $UEml);
  $qSQL->execute();
  $result = $qSQL->get_result();
  while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    return $row[0];
  }
//  return $row[0];
  if($qSQL) {
    return array(status => true);
  }
  else {
    return array(status => false, message => 'Not Found');
  }
}
```

and I call it from php script
**check-User.php**

```
<?php
require_once("db-config.php");
include 'functions.php';
...
$UsID = get_userID("joe@example.com");
echo 'UserID: <span style="color: blue">'. $UsID ."</span>";
...
?>
```

**db-config.php**

```
<?php
// Two options for connecting to the database:

define('HOST_DIRECT', 'example.com'); // Standard connection
define('HOST_LOCAL', '127.0.0.1');    // Secure connection, slower performance

define('DB_HOST', HOST_DIRECT);         // Choose HOST_DIRECT or HOST_STUNNEL, depending on your application's requirements

define('DB_USER', 'dbUser');    // MySQL account username
define('DB_PASS', 'SecretPas');    // MySQL account password
define('DB_NAME', 'DBName');     // Name of database
 
// Connect to the database
$DB = new MySQLi(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

if ($DB->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $DB->connect_error);
}
//echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

I tried many variations, but no luck and also checked many similar posts here, but just can't get it working.
Thanks

Comment: `$DB` is not available in the function.

Comment: Don't escape data if you're using prepared queries. It's not necessary and can lead to corruption.

Comment: what you get right now? btw your echo statement is wrong.

Comment: @u_mulder so it's not enough to include it in the main php file.  I tried put include into the function, but still no result

Comment: I get nothing - no value- @GiacomoM even though SQL statement works.  I put escape statement at the end when I was out of ideas what else is wrong

Comment: Obviously `$DB` is not defined. Your question is very unclear since you should see something at least a notice

Comment: @Dharman when I removed escape statment I get result `#Array`

Comment: Where is `$DB` meant to come from? Did you create mysqli connection anywhere? You need to pass it as a parameter to the function.

Comment: Yes I have a connection php file, where I define parameters and initiate db.  I also have another function in **functions.php** which INSERT into db and is working fine.  Something is wrong in returning array instead of string, but not sure how to return a string

Comment: That was a problem .... pasing **$DB** to the function... Now is working. I somehow overlooked it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of errors here:

- $DB is not available in the function
- the `echo` statement is wrong

This is the code without these 2 errors:

```
function get_userID($DB, $UEml) 
{
    // Check database connection
    if ( ($DB instanceof MySQLi) == false) {
        return array(status => false, message => 'MySQL connection is invalid');
    }

    $qSQL = "SELECT UsID FROM Users WHERE UsEml=? LIMIT 1";
    $qSQL = $DB->prepare($qSQL);
    $qSQL->bind_param("s", $UEml);
    $qSQL->execute();
    $result = $qSQL->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        return $row[0];
    }
    //  return $row[0];
    // I do not know why you wrote this code. If you get an user this code will not be executed
    if ($qSQL) {
        return array(status => true);
    } else {
        return array(status => false, message => 'Not Found');
    }
}
```

And your `echo`:

```
// ...
$UsID = get_userID($DB, "joe@example.com");
echo "UserID: <span style=\"color: blue\">{$UsID}</span>";
```

Comment: it doesn't work with global $DB  in breaks the script

Comment: @Dharman of course you can do it. your choice

Comment: @Denis are you sure $DB variable is available in the PHP file?